# Lentitud en la compilación del proyecto IntelliJ con Vaadin y Spring Boot

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, vaadin

tengo un proyecto desarrollado en IntelliJ con Spring Boot y Vaadin. El proyecto enormemente pesado (166 MB) y tarda mucho en generarse y abrir la primera vista en el navegador Web. Intuyo que es debido a la configuración del `pom.xml` relacionada con Vaadin.

Archivo `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

¿Existe alguna forma de optimizarlo?

Comment: Cómo estás compilando el proyecto? Cómo estás ejecutando el proyecto? Qué parte del proceso es la que tarda más precisamente?